# How can I change props on the root Vue instance?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a Vue app which implements an embeddable widget (a JupyterLab widget specifically). The widget takes two major properties, which are URLs to images to load.

I know how to set initial props on the root instance:

```js
export default function createWidget(props={}) {
  return new Vue({
    store,
    render: h => h(App, { props })
  })
}
```

How can I change props to trigger a VDOM diffing "re-render"?

I know I can just create a new Vue() app and destroy the old one, but this is really expensive in my case. If I was embedding this as a sub-component in a Vue app, changing a prop and having the regular VDOM diff re-render would be perfect.... now just trying to do this from outside the Vue box.